# Deleting a field in nested objects in JQ

Tags: json, key, jq

I have a JSON lines file with `summary` fields and other fields.  I would like to delete all of the summary fields using JQ.  This is my input:

```
{"object1": {"summary":"Some summary I want removing", "keepMe":"please"}}
{"object2": {"summary":"Delete me too!", "keepMe":"pretty please"}}
```

and this is the desired output:

```
{"object1": {"keepMe":"please"}}
{"object2": {"keepMe":"pretty please"}}
```

Comment: @Inian - It looks like valid JSON Lines to me, and more relevantly, to jq.

Comment: @Inian - Yes, but that's irrelevant. jq is stream-oriented, and so can handle JSON Lines.

Comment: @Inian - You might like to look at my "Stream-Oriented Introduction to jq" (https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq). Comments would be welcome.

Comment: @peak: Looks great already! you should definitely link this to the tag wiki. Personally I found hard to cope up the original documentation when I was starting up with `jq`. Should be really useful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several possible interpretations of the Q.

A simple approach that will solve the simplest interpretation would be to use:

```
map_values(del(.summary))
```

If you want to eliminate the "summary" field wherever it occurs, no matter how deeply nested, then I'd use `walk/1`, e.g.

```
walk(if type == "object" then del(.summary) else . end)
```

Comment: My summary fields are always one level down so map_values was the key piece I was missing in my attempts!  Thanks a lot