# Regex - how to remove specific string from a long file

Tags: json, regex

I have this json file with this data:

```
"json": {
    "3.0": {
        "path": "sfsdfsdfsf",
        "release": {
            "id": 14211,
            "version": "2017061400",
            "release": "sdfsdfsfd",
            "maturity": 200,
            "downloadurl": "sfdfsfdfds",
            "downloadmd5": "sffsdfs",
            "vcssystem": "git",
            "vcssystemother": null,
            "vcsrepositoryurl": "dsfdsfsdf",
            "vcsbranch": null,
            "vcstag": "v1.6",
            "timecreated": 1497462295,
            "test": [
                {
                    "version": 2015102300,
                    "release": "3.0"
                }
            ]
        },
        "file": "fsdfdsfsd",
        "url": "sdfsdfsdf"
    }
```

And I need a way in my editor using regex to remove this first "release" object. I was trying to figure it out but not successful to get rid of it.

I tried a lot of things for example:

```
"release": {([^}]+)\},
```

This will remove  all till the first closing curly bracket, but don't know how to come to remove everything until this "file" section.
How to tell regex, go on, until you find the file section?

Comment: Regexes are not the right tool for this job. If you have Bash, check out the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser. Or do it by hand, if you need to change a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while regexes are not the right tools for this, it can be done using a regex.

see: [regex](https://regex101.com/r/50d41i/1)

The used regex: `("release": {[ "a-zA-Z:0-9,\r\n\.[{}\]]*)(?="file")`

- Match `"release": {`
- then match any chcaracters like  `"a-zA-Z:0-9,\r\n\.[{}\]` zero or more times.
- `(?="file")` do a "positive lookahead" for `"file"`

EDIT:

A solution using `jq` (with help from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57489062/724039 ):

```
jq 'walk(if type=="object" then del(.release) else . end)' input.json
```

or:

```
jq 'del(.json."3.0".release)' input.json
```